# How to remove an extra cycle?

Tags: c

I need to make the code more readable, but it has a lot of cycle, can I fix this somehow?

The variable `i` constantly jumps there and there, it is very inconvenient to watch in debugging.

```
for(;;)
{
    //
    // For connection orientated protocols, we will handle the
    // packets received from a connection collectively.  For datagram
    // protocols, we have to handle each datagram individually.
    //

    //
    // Check to see if we have any sockets remaining to be served
    // from previous time through this loop.  If not, call select()
    // to wait for a connection request or a datagram to arrive.
    //

    for (i = 0; i < numSocket; i++)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(servSock[i], &SockSet))
            break;
    }

    if (i == numSocket)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < numSocket; i++)
        {
            FD_SET(servSock[i], &SockSet);
        }

        if (select(numSocket, &SockSet, 0, 0, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            continue;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numSocket; i++)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(servSock[i], &SockSet))
        {
            FD_CLR(servSock[i], &SockSet);
            break;
        }
    }

...

}
```

Comment: You might want to post this code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: By "cycle", do you maybe mean "loop"?

Comment: Forgive me. I don't know much English.

Comment: Use separate loop variables.  Don’t reuse `i` for multiple purposes.

Comment: Now would be the perfect time for Captain Needa to come by.

Comment: `I need to make the code more readable` the biggest problem about readability here is that it is not clear what each part of the code should do. So you should add some comments at critical parts of the code. And only reuse variables if it is really necessary. What situation does the  `if (i == numSocket)` detect?

Comment: @t.niese NumSocket stores information on how many servSock was created; in this case there are 2
first IPv4
second IPv6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the code more readable (and testable and maintainable) you can encapsulate some of the logic into separate functions with meaningful names. Consider this version of your loop

```
for(;;)
{
    int i = find_socket_to_be_served(numSocket, servSock, &SockSet);

    if (i == numSocket)
    {
        set_all_sockets(numSocket, servSock, &SockSet);

        if (select(numSocket, &SockSet, 0, 0, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            continue;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Where the two functions used are defined as

```
int find_socket_to_be_served(int n_sockets, int *fds, fd_set *fdset)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < n_sockets; i++)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(fds[i], fdset))
        {
            FD_CLR(fds[i], fdset);
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

void set_all_sockets(int n_sockets, int *fds, fd_set *fdset)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n_sockets; i++)
    {
        FD_SET(fds[i], fdset);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your code, you don't need `FD_CLEAR()` your sockets one by one.
Just `FD_ZERO()` all of them at once, then use a single loop to `FD_SET()` them again.
Note that after `select()`, many sockets could be ready to use; you don't have to `break` when one has been used.
Note also that the first parameter of `select()` is unused on Windows but should be **1+** the **max** of your socket file descriptors (not the number of them) everywhere else.

```
for(;;)
{
    FD_ZERO(&SockSet);
    for (int i = 0; i < numSocket; i++)
    {
        FD_SET(servSock[i], &SockSet);
    }
    if (select(numSocket, &SockSet, 0, 0, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        continue; // or probably break...
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numSocket; i++)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(servSock[i], &SockSet))
        {
            // use servSock[i]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have PF_INET and PF_INET6 stored there, so this is most likely needed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/ipv6-enabled-server-code-2

Comment: @DarthVader Then if you assume that all of this is needed what do you want to simplify?

Comment: I want to rewrite everything so that the code becomes more understandable than now.